# how to autoset all the components of jFrame while maximizing it

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am getting one problem in jFrame
whenever i maximize my jFrame window then all the button ,Labels and textField get Scattered here in there 
can you please give me some solution for this.

coding part:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    jMenuBar1.setVisible(false);
    LoginPanel.setVisible(true);
}

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String _password = new String(PasswordField.getPassword());
    String _loginid = LoginField.getText();

    System.out.println("Password --->>"+_password);
    System.out.println("Loginid --->>"+_loginid);

    if(_loginid.equalsIgnoreCase(username)){
        if(_password.equalsIgnoreCase(password)){
            LoginPanel.setVisible(false);
            jMenuBar1.setVisible(true);
            DateLabel.setText("12 April 2015");
            NoOfStudentLabel.setText("300");
            NoOfProffesorPanel.setText("50");
        }


public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
String username="admin";
String password="12345";

private javax.swing.JLabel DateLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField LoginField;
private javax.swing.JPanel LoginPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel MainPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel NoOfProffesorPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel NoOfStudentLabel;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField PasswordField;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem SearchStudent;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem SearchTeacher;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem7;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem8;
```

so guys please tell me what should i do for this issue.
i mean to say that when i maximize my jFrame then all the components should be auto set and same when i minimize to its default size

Comment: Use layout managers to help you arrange your components nicely, neatly and in ways that resize smartly. The specifics will depend on the specifics of your problem, including the layout that you're trying to achieve, and how you're coding it now, somethings you've not yet told us.

Comment: For example, you state, `"whenever i maximize my jFrame window then all the button ,Labels and textField get Scattered here in there..."` -- but it's quite difficult to guess what you might be doing wrong since you show none of your layout and add component code.

Comment: i have already pasted the code..so tell me what is need to include in my code

Comment: The most important code, the `initComponents()` method is where you layout all your components. You've not posted that.

Comment: please go to 3rd line of my code

Comment: I've gone through **all** your code. That line just calls `initComponents()`. You've not shown the method at all! But I'm going to guess -- that you've created your GUI using NetBeans drag and drop, aka GroupLayout, and that this is hampering you. If so, the answer to your problem is the same as the duplicate question that I've closed your question with: learn and use layout managers.

Comment: snapshot before maximize
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98634288/before%20mazimize.JPG

Comment: after maximize
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98634288/after%20mazimizing.JPG

Comment: Again, learn and use layout managers. [Google: java swing layout manager tutorial](https://www.google.com/?q=java+swing+layout+manager+tutorial&gws_rd=ssl#q=java+swing+layout+manager+tutorial). First hit -- then read/study the docs.